# Computing second order partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I am tasked with the following question:

> Consider the wave equation for linearly $x$ polarised waves travelling in the $\pm z$ directions: 
>   $$\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial z^2}\tag{1}$$
>   Transform Eq. $(1)$ to the independent variables $q = z − ct$ and $s = z + ct$ and show
>   that
>   $$\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s \partial q}=0$$

When I am confronted with questions of this type I always use the 'tree diagram for partial derivatives' method which is outlined in this video - [Chain rule and tree diagrams of multivariable functions (KristaKingMath)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NircIRdNUrE&t=596s) by Krista King.

So writing 
$$E_{x}=E_{x}(q,s)$$
$$q=q(z,t) \qquad\text{and}\qquad s=s(z,t)$$
then
$$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial s}\cdot\frac{\partial s}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial q}\cdot\frac{\partial q}{\partial z}$$

Now since $q = z − ct$ and $s = z + ct$

$$\frac{\partial s}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial q}{\partial z}=1$$
then

$$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial q}\tag{a}$$

Now with respect to time:

$$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial q}\cdot\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial s}\cdot\frac{\partial s}{\partial t}$$

Since,
$$-\frac{\partial q}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial s}{\partial z}=c$$
then
$$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial t}=c\biggl(\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial s}-\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial q}\biggr)\tag{b}$$

From $(\mathrm{a})$ (since it holds for all functions)

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial z}=\frac{\partial }{\partial s}+\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\tag{2}$$

So differentiating $(\mathrm{b})$ wrt $z$ using $(2)$

$$\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial z \partial t}=c\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial s}+\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\right)\left(\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial s}-\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial q}\right)=c\left(\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s^2}-\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s \partial q}+\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q \partial s}-\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q^2}\right)$$
$$=c\left(\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s^2}-\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q^2}\right)$$

So the expression that I wanted to show is zero,
$$\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s \partial q}$$ has cancelled out of the expression. Here I have assumed that $E_x$ is sufficiently 'well-behaved' such that $$\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s \partial q}=\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q \partial s}$$

---

This is the answer given by the author:

[image: answer]

---

Since the solution given by the author doesn't explicitly show that 
$$\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s \partial q}=0,$$

could someone please explain how I can show that it is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $\dfrac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s \partial q}=0$ compute the second partial derivatives in the original PDE, $\dfrac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial t^2}-c^2\dfrac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial z^2}=0$ in terms of the partial derivatives wrt to the new variables. In fact, you did it half the way as you did it for the first derivatives,

$$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial q}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial t}=c\biggl(\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial s}-\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial q}\biggr)\tag{b}$$

So,

$$\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial z^2}=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial s}+\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\right)\left(\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial q}\right)=\left(\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s^2}+2\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q \partial s}+\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q^2}\right)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial t^2}=c\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial s}-\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\right)c\left(\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial s}-\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial q}\right)=c^2\left(\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s^2}-2\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q \partial s}+\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q^2}\right)$$

Substituting:

$$0=\dfrac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial t^2}-c^2\dfrac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial z^2}=c^2\left(\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s^2}-2\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q \partial s}+\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q^2}\right)-c^2\left(\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial s^2}+2\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q \partial s}+\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q^2}\right)=$$

$$=-4c^2\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q \partial s}$$

which means,

$$\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial q \partial s}=0$$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write out all the steps in full, it was such a bad mistake I made by mixing the partial derivatives and not using the pde. +1

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Notation: let $E_x:=E$, $\partial_s:=\partial/\partial s$, $\partial_s^2:= \partial^2/\partial s^2$, etc.

You already found the first derivatives in the new variables. Let's write this in a suggestive way of the new conjugate (up to $c$) differential operators. $$\begin{align*} \partial_z E = (\partial_s  + \partial_q) E, \\ \partial_t E = c(\partial_s  - \partial_q)E\end{align*} $$

Then, just like the familiar ring of polynomials, we have a (non-commutative) ring of differential operators with$$\begin{align*}\partial_z = \partial_s + \partial_q \Rightarrow \partial_z^2 &= \partial_s^2 + 2\partial_{qs}+\partial_q^2, \\ \partial_t = c(\partial_s - \partial_q)\Rightarrow\partial_t^2 &= c^2(\partial_s^2-2\partial_{qs}+\partial_q^2)\end{align*} $$

As $E(t,z)$ satisfies the wave equation, $\partial_{qs}E = 0.$

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer, sadly my votes don't count yet as have < 15 rep.

Comment: No worries! It’s rough at first. Welcome to SE. I voted/favorited your question and hope it helps a little.